# Clarification using closures in IEnumerator coroutines

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, closures, functor, coroutine

I have 2 IEnumerator coroutines that are similar enough that they should be combined:

A:

```
IEnumerator CountDown_A() {
  timeLeft_A = totalTime_A;
  while (timeLeft_A > 0) {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1); 
    timeLeft_A--;
  }
}
```

B:

```
IEnumerator CountDown_B() {
  timeLeft_B = totalTime_B;
  while (timeLeft_B > 0) {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1); 
    timeLeft_B--;
  }
}
```

The only 2 differences are the variables `totalTime_A` vs `totalTime_B` and `timeLeft_A` vs `timeLeft_B`. These vars are from outside the scope of this function.

The problem I'm having modularizing this coroutine is that the incremented value of `timeLeft_A` and `timeLeft_B` needs to apply outside this function, so I need to pass a reference to them somehow.

User "Kurt-Dekker" posted a great solution in [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/c-passing-and-changing-variables-using-a-coroutine.358309/) but I'm having trouble applying it to my code. He says to "use a closure (functor) to allow the coroutine to modify it by callback":

```
IEnumerator CountDown( System.Action<int> callback){
    ....
}
```

which I think would be called like so:

```
StartCoroutine ( CountDown( (i) => { timeLeft_A = i; } ) );
StartCoroutine ( CountDown( (i) => { timeLeft_B = i; } ) );
```

What I don't understand is how to then reference/modify the actual value of the int being passed in, inside the IEnumerator, if all I have to work with is a callback function. For example to do the following:

```
while(callback > 0){
```

or:

```
callback--;
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking... Do you need to pass a parameter to your coroutine ?

Comment: Ho ok, after a second read I understand now :) 
The countdown variable is modified outside of the coroutine right ?

Comment: Yes I basically need to pass `timeLeft_A`  into `CountDown_A()` by reference (value needs to change globally).

Comment: But I'd like `CountDown_A()` and `CountDown_B()` to be the same function, so maybe `CountDown()`. So the global vars can't be explicitly named inside.

Comment: Why don't you use a member/property in the class you are  calling the coroutine ?

Comment: Ho ok nevermind.. I will try to find a solution for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may answer your question, on how to use the `System.Action<float>` within a coroutine.

Basicaly, when you call `StartCoroutine` you give the maximum time for you counter as a normal parameter and a callback, this callback takes a float as argument (here it is **i**).

If you call `callback(--timeLeft);` in your coroutine, it will execute the `System.Action` you passed in.

Here it will set the `timeLeft_A` or `timeLeft_B` to the `timeLeft` variable of the corresponding coroutine.

```
public float timeLeft_A = 0f;
public float timeLeft_B = 0f;

public float totalTime_A = 15f;
public float totalTime_B = 20f;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(Cooldown(totalTime_A, (i) =>
    {
        timeLeft_A = i;
    }));

    StartCoroutine(Cooldown(totalTime_B, (i) =>
    {
        timeLeft_B = i;
    }));
}

IEnumerator Cooldown(float totalTime, Action<float> callback)
{
    var timeLeft = totalTime;
    while (timeLeft > 0)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        callback(--timeLeft);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to do this! I'll try it out soon.

Answer (score 0):

Just putting my implementation here for posterity, based off Antoine Thiry's answer.

```
private static int totalTime_A = 45; // Num seconds
private int timeLeft_A = totalTime_A;
private static int totalTime_B = 30; // Num seconds
private int timeLeft_B = totalTime_B;

// Pass in totalTime separately from the callback (totalTime doesn't need to change)
IEnumerator CountDown(int totalTime, Action<int> callback){
  int timeLeft = totalTime; // Create new local var here to operate on it
  while (timeLeft > 0) {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    callback(--timeLeft); // Then put the local var into callback after operating on it
  }
}
```

`CountDown()` called like so:

```
// timeLeft_A and timeLeft_B change globally
IEnumerator Countdown_A = CountDown(totalTime_A, (i) => { timeLeft_A = i; });
IEnumerator Countdown_B = CountDown(totalTime_B, (i) => { timeLeft_B = i; });
StartCoroutine(Countdown_A);
StopCoroutine(Countdown_A);
StartCoroutine(Countdown_B);
StopCoroutine(Countdown_B);
```